# Calling .clone() too many times in vb, will it cause any trouble?

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio, shallow-copy

I am an embedded engineer and I have never worked with neither windows nor visual basic.
For my current task I have to maintain and improve a test system running on Windows, written in Visual Studio, C#(also have no experience with) .
This project uses some libraries written in visual basic(all legacy code). And I detect a problem in there. I cannot copy the code directly in here but because of legal bindings but it is something like that:

```
'getter()
dim temp as byte = global_data
Array.reverse(temp);
...
```

This is a getter function. Since there is a reverse inside, the return of this function is different after each call because when temp changed, global_data is also changed. And I can get the real value only after odd number of calls. Previous handler told me to call function only once or three times... I think this is stupid and changed it by adding a .clone() like this:

```
dim temp as byte = global_data.clone()
Array.reverse(temp);
```

And it worked :)
There are a lot of functions like this so I'm gonna make similar adjustments to them too.
But since I am not familiar with the dynamics of this system, I am afraid to face with a problem later. For example can making multiple number of clones consume my RAM? Can those clones be destroyesd? If yes, do I have to destroy them? How?
Or are there any other possible problems?
And is there an other way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `global_data` looks like an array, not a function, unless it returns an existing Field value (but it'd seem *dumb*). Cloning the array in a method as `dim temp as byte() = DirectCast(global_data.clone(), byte())` affects the method where `temp` is defined, then it will go out of scope. Having `Option Strict On` helps a lot, try to set it as default.

Comment: Did I imply that it is a function? If so i can correct. It is a global variable. It is defined in other place but called in here so I think it is global like the global variables in C. I will check that option. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, no there is nothing wrong with calling `Clone` multiple times.
The cloned byte arrays will take up memory as long as they are referenced, but that isn't unique to the byte array being cloned.  Presumably that cloned byte array is being passed to other methods.  Once those methods are executed the array will be eligible for garbage collection, and the system will take care of it.  If this code runs very very frequently, there might be better approaches that are more efficient than allocating and eventual garbage collection of those arrays, but you won't "break" anything using the Clone over an over.

Answer (score 0):

For variables of basic type, clone method copies its value, which requires the stack to allocate space for it.
Value type allocates memory in the stack. They have their own life cycle, so they are automatically allocated and released without management. So you do not have to worry about taking a lot of memory, calling it many times will not cause trouble.